# Deserialize alternative names for the same class

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I have a serialier that is not totally unlike the following:

```
[Serializable]
public class MSG
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [XmlText]
    public string Content { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public MSG DeserializeMyMsg(string xmlstr)
{
    TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlstr);
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MSG));
    MSG ret = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as MSG;
    return ret;
}
```

This would successfully deserialize the following:

```
<MSG Name="woho">any content</MSG>
```

Occasionally data can arrive as:

```
<Mg Name="woho">any content</Mg>
```

How can I mark `Mg` as an alternative name for `MSG`?

---

MSG is the root. Fixing Mg would be the long term goal but is not an option either. The messages could be retrofitted with an outer root.

Comment: Has to be done at parent of the class.  You can't have alternate but can have both properties in the parent.

Comment: As far as I know: this simply isn't possible for the xml root object; you could *check* the outer element name and compensate, or use a wrapper object like in the comment above; but frankly, you should just find where the `<Mg>` ones are coming from, and fix that

Comment: Is Msg the root of the xml document?  If its part of a greater xml structure there are ways to do what you want but not if its at the root.

Comment: @TimRutter MSG is the root but the xml is stripped of  namespaces and xml docuemnt info. So wrapping it before parsing may be possible. `$"<NewRoot>{str}</NewRoot>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in a comment you could wrap your xml.  This feels an awful lot like a hack but this works.  Generally my advice would be don't do this!

So your xml would be:

```
<NewRoot><MSG Name="woho">any content</MSG></NewRoot>
```

Or

```
<NewRoot><Mg Name="woho">any content</Mg></NewRoot>
```

Then define these classes and deserialize the above xml:

```
public class NewRoot
{
    [XmlElement("MSG", typeof(MSG))]
    [XmlElement("Mg", typeof(Mg))]
    public MSG Msg {get;set;}
}

public class Mg : MSG {}
```

Comment: I found more that is incompatible, so I will follow the advice given in your answer and in multiple other comments and just not do it. I will declare my software incompatible with Mg messages instead.

Comment: Probably for the best, the answer still shows the sort of thing you can do with xml serialization so worth keeping.  There are other things you can do such as custom serializers, which may be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it is not directly possible with only modifying the serialization attributes. But what you could do, is introduce another type with different attributes and then adjust your deserialization logic to choose a proper serializer.

Model for legacy:

```
[XmlRoot("Mg")]
public class MSGLegacyWrapper : MSG { }
```

Deserialization logic:

```
public static MSG DeserializeMyMsg(string xmlstr)
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader(xmlstr))
    using (var xmlreader = XmlReader.Create(reader))
    using (var serializationReader = new StringReader(xmlstr))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MSG));
        var chosenSerializer = serializer.CanDeserialize(xmlreader)
            ? serializer 
            : new XmlSerializer(typeof(MSGLegacyWrapper));
        return chosenSerializer.Deserialize(serializationReader) as MSG;
    }
}
```

Ofc this could be pimped further to optimize the decision process.

**Alternative 1**

If you are already preprocessing the input then you could as well normalize the root tag name with string operations (ex regex) before deserializing to strongly typed model.

**Alternative 2**

If your schema is simple/stable enough, you could drop attribute-based deserialization and implement your own custom `XmlReader`  which CAN handle alternative root elements. See documentation and examples [from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx).
I believe if performance matters then this is the fastest option.